# How to import JSON data to BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Currently I am working on a project that where I use an API to get JSON data. I got it to where I can request the browser, but I want to take the next step and place that data produced by the URL into big query. I was wondering if there was a way to use the terminal to do it?

Comment: can you paste here the code you are using to get the JSON data and the JSON results? maybe someone could add the next line to get it into bigquery

Comment: https://<API SECRET>@mixpanel.com/api/2.0/events/?interval=7&type=average&event=["$custom_event:203517", "account-page"]&unit=day. I'm trying to get mixpanel JSON data into big query

Comment: paste the results into the question to see what kind of JSON you get?

Comment: {"legend_size": 2, "data": {"series": ["2016-08-06", "2016-08-07", "2016-08-08", "2016-08-09", "2016-08-10", "2016-08-11", "2016-08-12"], "values": {"$custom_event:203517": {"2016-08-10": 10.08433734939759, "2016-08-11": 5.563025210084033, "2016-08-12": 5.020833333333333, "2016-08-09": 6.023255813953488, "2016-08-06": 4.0, "2016-08-07": 10.0, "2016-08-08": 11.25}, "account-page": {"2016-08-10": 0, "2016-08-11": 0, "2016-08-12": 0, "2016-08-09": 0, "2016-08-06": 0, "2016-08-07": 0, "2016-08-08": 0}}}}

Comment: Do you want to get columns out of that JSON? Or one single column with the whole string would suffice?

Comment: Columns would probably be best I think.

Comment: Columns would be best, I agree - but the schema you pasted there doesn't translate easily to columns though.

Comment: If thats the case, I'm totally fine with the whole string. I'm just looking for a way to learn how to transfer the data from the URL request with mixpanels api into big query

Comment: easiest way would be to put these rows into a file, and run `bq load` (up to 1000 times per day per table).. would that work?

Comment: I'll give it a shot thanks!